# Name of project on ActionBar of every Activity

Tags: android

I am facing an issue since upgrading Android Studio to 2.2... whenever I create  a new activity in a project, the name of the project is getting displayed on the `ActionBar` of the new activity rather than the name of the new activity created. I have just learned intent and the transition from 1 activity to another is just fine but the action bar has the name of the project rather than the name of the current activity. What should i do?

Comment: *What should i do?* read the docs!

Comment: Check the layout file. It is probably pointing to an `AppName` string resource. Just type in activity name, or point to an `ActivityName` resource

Answer (score 0):

Declare `label` in manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".your_activity"
        android:label="name_your_activity_label"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".your_activity"
        android:label="name_your_activity_label" />
```

Example is just demonstration, edit in future. :P